# printf() prints twice the same line after signal handling

Tags: c, linux, multiprocessing, fork

I have this function (in a long program with semaphores, I'll attach any code if necessary):

```
void signalHandler(int signumber){
    /* for SIGINT */
    if(signumber == SIGINT){    
        printf(" Pressed - Stop the timer & start cleaning process...\n");      
        flag = 0; //relevant for the rest of the program
    }
}
```

when I'm running the program and press `CTRL+C` to stop it, instead of getting this output:

```
^C Pressed - Stop the timer & start cleaning process...

*****Timer finished / stopped - clean the queue*****
....
```

I get this output with double print:

```
^C Pressed - Stop the timer & start cleaning process...
 Pressed - Stop the timer & start cleaning process...

*****Timer finished / stopped - clean the queue*****
....
```

This little thing very annoying, how can I fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: `printf` is not async-signal-safe, so calling it in a signal handler produces undefined behavior.  Don't do that.

Comment: stdio is even called out in the third paragraph of [signal-safety(7)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)...

Comment: You have the tag [tag:fork] in the tags.  Do you set the signal handler before forking?  Both parent and child get the signal, so they would both print the message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ISO C, a signal handler may only set a volatile atomic flag, or abort the program .  In POSIX it [may also call some signal-safe functions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html), you will see that `printf` is not in the list.

So, basically, don't call printf from the signal handler.

Perhaps you could `write` to stdout, if going for POSIX conformance without ISO conformance. Or for the latter, set a flag in the signal handler and check that flag periodically from the main loop.